# Do I need to use redux-persist if I am trying to use firebase with my react native application?

Tags: react-native, redux, firebase-authentication, persistence

I am trying to check the authentication status of a user when he opens my react-native application. I have used redux-persist to get my react store to persist on the device after my application has closed. My question is do I need to do this if I am going to use firebase authentication ? What are the 'rules' with regard to using firebase and redux-persist together ? How to make sure they work together properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the whole point of redux-persist is to store the redux state even when the app is closed via either AsyncStorage/sql-lite-storage.

I believe previously you used to store your JWT token and check if its valid and show the user the respective screens.

Now since FirebaseAuth doesnt have any such flow, you can omit the loginReducer in redux persist configuration.
Like this :

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage,
  blacklist: ['navigation'] // navigation will not be persisted
};
```

But there may be some other places you use the redux store , like suppose i use redux persist to store the trip data of user, so it doesnt fetches every time. So just check out whats your purpose.

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts.

Comment: my problem was i had used redux persist only as a way to understand the concept as part of an online course. I tried using the default firebase persistence and it works fine. But as you said I might want to store other parts of the state and I haven't yet made a decision about that. I was just confused about how firebase default persistence and redux persist would interact. I think I will leave that exploration for some other day.

Comment: redux persist is nothing but a part of redux and redux workswell with firevbase then i dont think redux persists will create a problem

Comment: any idea on how i can clear the state persisted by redux persist? I cant get it to clear lol

Comment: blacklist: ['navigation'] is the one where you write your reducer which you dont want to save

Comment: No i mean i am going to remove persist from my application altogether. I wanted to know how to clear the local storage where the previously persisted state was stored. Turns out its persistor.purge()

Comment: @HarshaLimaye redux-persist is not being maintained anyways. No one should be using it.